# Parsing Windows Journal (JNT) files

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft.ink

According to [.NET docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348819.aspx), it should be possible to convert JNT files into XML using the `Microsoft.Ink.JournalReader.ReadFromStream` component.  However, all the code samples on MSDN are old and don't work with Windows 7 x64 and the current version of Windows Journal.  In particular, `JournalReader.ReadFromStream` throws a runtime type mismatch error when reading a JNT file stream.

The most recent code sample I could find targets .NET 3.0; [the API docs for .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348819.aspx) 
 describe the `JournalReader.ReadFromStream` component, but the code samples are blank.  Is there any up-to-date information on converting JNT format to XML?

Comment: I tried to read the windows journal files. See here: http://www.sapien.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=6386
The code should work (MAKE SURE to change all the paths in the code to an example file on your PC) but the needed program has a bug :(

Answer (score 1):

Please work on this. You could extract the text and merge it in an invisible layer with pdfs created from the JNTs. Then they would also be searchable.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to batch print them to PDF.  Then parse the PDF.  You can find scripts for batch printing to PDF in the [Journal Note to PDF](https://github.com/fmartelg/Journal-Note-to-PDF) repo.